# Accepting name of changed file in fswatch with xargs in osx

Tags: bash, macos, fswatch

In osx I am trying to detect when a new file is added to a folder, then execute a script to process that new file.  Seems simple, right?

I am doing this:

```
fswatch  -0  ~/motion-detection | xargs -0 -n1 -I {} ./detectmotion.sh
```

which will call the shell script detectmotion.sh which consists of:

```
echo "File added: " $1
```

for now, at least.  I just want to pass the filename of the changed file to detectmotion.sh

I get a blank for $1

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is expected to be *empty* because you are not passing the argument to the script `detectmotion.sh` which you got from `xargs`. It should have been

```
fswatch  -0  ~/motion-detection | xargs -0 -n1 -I {} ./detectmotion.sh "{}"
```

Remember that the `-I {}` flag in `xargs` represents a *place-holder* for the value pipe-lined to `xargs`. So in your attempt as part of the question, you are just storing the value in the place-holder(`{}`)  and not actually passing it to the script to make it useful.

So I modified the command so that you are actually passing the received value to the script which can now be printed when accessed as `$1` inside the script.

Quoting from the `man xargs` page for `-I`

```
-I replace-str
     Replace  occurrences  of  replace-str  in the initial-arguments with names read from 
     standard input.  Also, unquoted blanks do not terminate input items; instead the 
     separator is the newline character.  Implies -x and -L 1.
```

In our case the `replace-str` being used as `{}`.

Comment: @Uberbug: Glad you found it useful.